# Simulating a touch on a phone screen without a finger?

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, multi-touch

I'm trying to simulate a touch on my iPhone without actually touching it (with a finger) for an app I'm making, I already tried electricity and it didn't worked, what is the correct way of doing it?

edit: I'm trying to simulate a touch physically, I need to understand the touch screen mechanism to find some sort of material.

Comment: [Telekinesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychokinesis) perhaps? Are you trying to effect the actual touch on a physical iPhone, or just simulate touch on a virtual iPhone?

Comment: Sorry, should have stated, I'm trying to simulate a touch physically.

Comment: You can use a banana!

Answer (score 2):

Apple's screens are capacitive touch so you would need to have a 3D servo mechanism to move a sausage or one of those gloves with touch material weaved in to them.

Many food stuffs that contain water (sausage, snacks, string cheese) would work as well if you don't want to spend money on a device engineered to work with capacitive screens for whatever reason.

Programmatically, you would want to connect the iOS device to a Mac and run [Xcode Server from Server.app](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/features/) and/or enable [UI Automation testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/). Then you can script and even code the things you need your "electronic finger" to test. There are many, many videos on the internet covering the test frameworks and how to set this up.

Comment: the gloves don't work only because there's a human finger inside them?

Comment: also, can you elaborate your answer? anything with water in it will work? I didn't understood how they built the touch mechanism...

Comment: To understand [capacitive touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing) somewhat, there is much information on the subject.  A quick search will reveal how it works.

Answer (score 1):

A standard touch stylus is designed to work just a human finger on a captive screen.  Bonus is that your simulator doesn't start to smell after a couple days.

You have them with hard polymer tip but there's also cheaper ones with a softer, thin layered polymer layer over foam tip.  I don't know where you are from, but in Asian electronic malls they start at about 50 cents a pop.

[image]